# Spring MVC CSS Error Loading

Tags: java, html, css, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring and while running a page without css it is running perfectly. when I include my css file it looks plain without css. While clicking on the link in the View source it shows Error 404 . help me on this

Web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   ">


   <context:component-scan base-package="com.ksv" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/"  
    cache-period="31556926"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Controller:

```
package com.ksv;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {


      return "hello";
   }

}
```

JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>KSV</title>  
     <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    </head>
  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Login</h1>

                <form class="form" action="login" method="post">
            <input type="text" name = "username" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" name ="userpass" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" id="login-button">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <ul class="bg-bubbles">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>






  </body>
</html>
```

File Structure:

```
HelloWeb
    -WebContent
        -Meta-inf
        -resources
        -web-inf
            -jsp
            -hello.jsp
        -Servlet.xml
        -web.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove css/ from location attribute of mvc resource cnfiguration.

Change :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/"  
    cache-period="31556926"/>
```

to

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"  
    cache-period="31556926"/>
```

Comment: Great ! It worked ! Thanks a lot :) Can you please explain why the above method is not worked?

Comment: Because, in your example, any requests from this url pattern /resources/**, Spring will look for the resources from the /resources/css/ instead. So <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css", Spring will try to read it from location "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/css/style.css". (extra css is added to the path). With your configuration, you should either remove /css from configuration or from 'href' attribute. IMHO for more readability it is better to remove from configuration.